# Having trouble finding PPI for commodity using NAICS code

Tags: commodities, products

Is there a way to find the Producer price index for a commodity during two different years by using the NAICS code of the commodity.

For example, I know the NAICS code for cast iron steel bearings as 332991P and I want to find the PPI for it in 2002 and 2014. I tried to use the Bureau of Labor Statistics Websites but It it much more confusing than I thought it would be

Comment: In case you don't have any answers, you could try contacting the BLS. I've had some luck with these government offices responding for issues like this.